# Changing object geometry in three js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am currently trying to change the geometry of a cube in three js to that of a sphere after a certain time interval or an event click. I have tried to change the property of geometry from Three.BoxGeometry to Three.SphereGeometry but have had no luck.
I have also tried to implement some "solutions" that I found, but have hit a wall there too.

Here is what I initially had:

```js
export class ThreeJSService {
  geometry: THREE.BoxGeometry;
  camera: THREE.PerspectiveCamera;
  cube: THREE.Mesh;
  movingObject;
  renderer: THREE.WebGLRenderer;
  scene: THREE.Scene;
  texture: THREE.Texture;
  /**
   * Setups scene for 3d objects
   */
  constructor() {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
    this.texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load('assets/apartment_background.png');
    this.scene.background = this.texture;

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();

    this.geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
    const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x348713} );
    this.cube = new THREE.Mesh( this.geometry, material );

    this.movingObject = {
      object: this.cube,
      geometry: this.geometry,
      direction: {
        x: 0.03,
        y: 0,
      },
    };
  }

  /**
   * Sets all the requirements needed for the scene
   * @param {HTMLElement} parent The element to attach to
   */
  setup(parent: HTMLElement) {
    const canvas = this.renderer.domElement;
    this.scene.add( this.cube );

    this.camera.position.z = 5;
    parent.appendChild(canvas);
  }

  // transform() {
  //   for ( var i = 0, l = this.geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i ++ ) {
  //
  //     var vertex = this.geometry.vertices[ i ];
  //     vertex.normalize().multiplyScalar( 550 );
  //
  //   //  After a certain interval change the geometry from Cylinder to Sphere
  //
  //   }
  // }

  /**
   * Provides animation to the rendered object. Makes the cube move and sends it to another direction when getting to the border
   * @param {number | undefined} headerHeight The height of the header
   */
  animate() {
    const header = document.getElementById('header')?.clientHeight;
    this.renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight - (header ? header : 0));

    this.movingObject.object.rotateX(0.01);
    this.movingObject.object.rotateY(0.01);
    requestAnimationFrame( this.animate.bind(this) );
    this.renderer.render( this.scene, this.camera );

    this.movingObject.object.position.x += this.movingObject.direction.x;

    // Check if the position of the cube is on the border
    if (this.cube.position.x > 7.3 || this.cube.position.x < -7.3) {
      this.movingObject.direction.x = -this.movingObject.direction.x;
    }
  }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete live example that shows a geometry is replaced after two seconds.

```js
let camera, scene, renderer;

init();
render();

function init() {

  camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(70, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.01, 10);
  camera.position.set(2, 2, 2);
  camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0);

  scene = new THREE.Scene();

  geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
  material = new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial();

  mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(mesh);

  renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
  renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
  renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
  document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

  setTimeout(function() {

    mesh.geometry.dispose();
    mesh.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry();

    render();

  }, 2000);

}

function render() {

  renderer.render(scene, camera);

}
```

```css
body {
      margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.141/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried that implementation. However, the object does not take time between swtiching shapes for a set time interval. I used "setInterval" intsead of "setTimeout". It just flashes very fast from a cube to sphere.

Comment: Please show what you do with a editable live example: https://jsfiddle.net/f2Lommf5/

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it to work.
This is my solution:

```js
 changeShape() {
    this.interval = (Math.floor(Math.random() * (400 + 1)) * 1000);
    // this.interval = Math.floor((Math.random() * (20 - 10 + 10)) + 10) * 1000;

    if (this.switch) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.movingObject.object.geometry.dispose();
        this.movingObject.object.geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 2);

        this.switch = false;

        // console.log(this.interval);

      }, this.interval);

    } else {
      setTimeout(() => {

        this.movingObject.object.geometry.dispose();
        this.movingObject.object.geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(0.5, 8, 8);
        this.switch = true;

        // console.log(this.interval);

      }, this.interval);
    }
  }
```

Thank you for the assist!